# cssClass on alert not working

Tags: angular, ionic2, alert

I'm trying to customize the alerts on my app. I've used this code

```
youWinAlert() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    message: "message!",
    title: "Title",
    buttons: ['Ok'],
    cssClass: "winAlert",
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

I think the custom class is supposed to appear next to `alert-wrapper` in the html code but it doesn't. Am I forgetting something?

```
Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
```

Comment: where is the css defined?

Comment: first on the page scss then on the app/app.scss, but the problem is that it doesn't show up in the html code of the page